# JPA 2.1.1, Eclipselink 2.5.0, ORACLE 12c and Array of Structs

Tags: jpa

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE "RD_PHN_TY" AS  OBJECT (
    PHN_TYP_CD VARCHAR2(1) ,
    PHN_NBR    VARCHAR2(30) )

   CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE "RD_PHN_NT" AS TABLE OF RD_PHN_TY;

   CREATE TABLE RD_CUSTOMER (
   CUSTOMER_ID NUMBER ,
   FIRST_NAME  VARCHAR2(20) ,
   LAST_NAME   VARCHAR2(20) ,
   PHN_TXT RD_PHN_NT , --- nested table
   OFC_PHN RD_PHN_TY , --- struct
   CONSTRAINT PK_CUSTOMER PRIMARY KEY (CUSTOMER_ID) )
   NESTED TABLE PHN_TXT STORE AS PHN_TAB;
```

I have two fields- ofcPhn(OFC_PHN) is of RD_PHN_TY(struct) and phnTxt(PHN_TXT) is an array of RD_PHN_TY(s). I am able to persist ofcPhn using StructConverter but not the phnTxt. My Customer entity and RdPhnTy object is shown below. Any help would be appreciated!

### Customer Entity

```
   @Entity
   @StructConverters( {
     @StructConverter(name = "phoneConverter", converter = 
                "com.pete.spotify.eclipselink.converter.PhoneTypeConverter")
   })
   public class Customer implements Serializable {
   ........
   private List<Phn> phnTxt;
   private Phn ofcPhn;
   ........

  @Convert("phoneConverter")
  @Column(name = "OFC_PHN", columnDefinition = "RD_PHN_TY")
  public Phn getOfcPhn () {
    return this.ofcPhn ;
  }

   public void setOfcPhn (Phn ofcPhn ) {
    this.ofcPhn = ofcPhn ;
   }
   }

 RdPhnTy
 -------
   public class RdPhnTy {
   private  String phnTypCd;
   protected String phnNbr;

   public RdPhnTy() {
   }

  @Column(name = "PHN_TYP_CD")
  public String getPhnTypCd() {
    return phnTypCd;
  }

  public void setPhnTypCd(String phnTypCd) {
    this.phnTypCd = phnTypCd;
  }

  @Column(name = "PHN_NBR")
  public String getPhnNbr() {
    return phnNbr;
  }

  public void setPhnNbr(String phnNbr) {
    this.phnNbr = phnNbr;
  }
  }
```